# Android InstantApp: Foreground service

Tags: android, service, android-instant-apps, foreground-service

Unable to use foreground service inside InstantApp feature module. Getting below runtime security exception.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{*.*.XYZActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Method
>   class android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getServices not available to
>   instant apps

Android document says,

> **Restricted features:** Run on the device without users being aware. **Foreground services are available.** Instant apps can only be started through activities that support App Links, so services,
>   content providers or broadcast receivers won't be able to start your
>   app.

Code:

```
// Starting service
getAppContext().startService(new Intent(getAppContext(), FirebaseAuthService.class));


// Foreground service class
public class FirebaseAuthService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseAuthService";
    private boolean isRunning = false;

    private String mUserId;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Service onCreate");

        startForeground();
        isRunning = true;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onStartCommand");

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                myTask();
            }
        }).start();

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onBind");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        isRunning = false;
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onDestroy");
    }

    private void startForeground() {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.noti_logo)
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setContentText("Preparing...")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

        startForeground(1337, notification);
    }

    private void myTask() {
         // At end
        // Stop service once it finishes its task
        stopSelf();
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick question : could you confirm to be that the pending intent returned from PendingIntent.getActivity is not null ? Not that it's related it is directly related to the issue you're having but I'm seeing that no pending intents are created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct but Foreground services are not working at the moment due to a known issue in Instant Apps supervisor.

Comment: Do you have ticket id?

Comment: Unfortunately not publicly visible.

Comment: It's been 7 years, has there been any update on this?